# Android resource pre-scaling instant

Tags: android, performance

According to [Android's practices guide on multiple screen support](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), when you don't provide the image resources for the device's density, the system automatically scales the existing resources accordingly.

The following application manifest flag makes the system scale the images in runtime and on-request:

```
android:anyDensity="false"
```

My question is: if you don't set this flag, when does the system perform this resources scale? Is it when the application process is created or during the apk's installation?

Answer (score 0):

> when you don't provide the image resources for the device's density,
>   the system automatically scales the existing resources accordingly.

This means that when your application inflates ImageView if you have 1 image resource and device has smaller/larger density system just scale's the image to fit with devices screen.

To answer your question: System scales the resource when that resource is needed, aka process creation.